# Differential Equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the entire problem below:

According to a simple physiological model, an athletic adult male needs 20 calories per day per pound of body weight to maintain his weight. If he consumes more or fewer calories than those required to maintain his weight, his weight changes at a rate proportional to the difference between the number of calories consumed and the number needed to maintain his current weight; the constant of proportionality is 1/3500 pounds per calorie. Suppose that a particular person has a constant caloric intake of H calories per day. Let W(t) be the person's weight in pounds at time t (measured in days).

(a) What differential equation has solution W(t)?

So I already solved for this and got that part correct. My answer was: $$\frac{dW}{dt} = \frac{1}{3500}(H-20W)$$
Below is the part that I am unsure of what to do:

(b) If the person starts out weighing 165 pounds and consumes 3500 calories a day,$$\lim_{t\to \infty} W(t) = \text{?}$$

I at first thought to plug in the H(3500) and W(165) values that were given in the part b question into the answer I got for part A. But then I wasn't sure what to do with that answer, or if that is even the way to go. It's probably a simple solution, but I'm not seeing where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try solving the differential equation $dW/dt=(1/3500)(H-20W)$?

Comment: Solving for it in what way? The only thing I had thought to do was plug in the values for H and W. But I'm pretty sure that isn't anywhere near what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: So, wait – you don't know what it means, to solve a differential equation? To solve an algebraic equation is to find the number $x$ that makes the equation true; to solve a differential equation is to find the function ($W$, in the case at hand) that makes the equation true. Have you not learned methods for solving differential equations?

Comment: Our professor is very hands off, in that he basically does zero teaching. So we're basically left to our own devices. If I did, I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Well then the thing to do is to post the question, "How do I solve this differential equation?" That would have saved two hours of toing and froing.

Comment: This particular differential equation is separable. It is also linear, first order. There are methods for solving each type of DE. Usually one learns how to solve separable DEs first. Have you studied how to solve separable DEs?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: the exercise can be handled without explicit resolution of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

When the weight stabilizes (at infinity), the derivative cancels out and

$$H-20W_\infty=0.$$

Answer (score -1):

We're told,

1. the guy needs 20 calories per day per pound of body weight to maintain his weight, and
2. he consumes 3500 clories a day.

It follows that if he weighs $3500\div20=175$ pounds, then he will stay at 175 pounds. If he weighs any less than 175 pounds (and consumes 3500 calories per day), his weight will increase; if he weighs any more than 175 pounds, his weight will decrease. It follows that, no matter what he weighs, his weight will, in the long run, approach 175 pounds.

Strictly speaking, there's a bit of handwaving going on here, and one ought to solve the differential equation to get a function $W(t)$, and then evaluate $\lim_{t\to\infty}W(t)$ – but at the very least the handwaving argument tells you what answer to expect.

As for how to solve the differential equation, if your teacher really expects you to solve the differential equation, and doesn't supply you with the tools for doing so, you have a case of academic malpractice, and should go to the head of the department to inform her. But first make absolutely sure that you have not, in fact, been given the tools to solve the equation!

Comment: I see what you mean now. And unfortunately, I ended up getting to that answer at some point last night and put it in--only to find out that she put in an error I guess in the database we use to provide answers :/ But seeing the entire explanation is helpful. I would go to the department head but she's had so many complaints against her and has never been removed as a teacher. So I'm kind of stuck with her until the semester is over. At any rate, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: uhmm, maybe talk to their teacher first?